# My jQuery isn't working, imported CDN, run after page is ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have imported jQuery from the CDN and try to do this:

```
$('th').click(() => {
        this.css("background-color", "rgba(23, 162, 184, 0.3)");

        if (lastClickedID === this.id) {
                direction === "asc" ? direction = "desc" : direction = "asc"; 
                $('#text-center').load('/Index?handler=OrderTablePartial&col=' + this.id + '&dir=' + direction + '&pageNo=' + page);
        }
        else {
                lastClickedID = this.id;
                $('#text-center').load('/Index?handler=OrderTablePartial&col=' + this.id + '&dir=' + direction + '&pageNo=' + page);
        }
})
```

But when I hit the table header nothing happens

Comment: not enoug code to understand problem. What is not working one. What do you expect? What is direction ,lastClickedID  ? please share more info

Comment: Please show us the html code.

Comment: Arrow functions used for an event handler, paired with the usage of `this`.  Common issue.